# how to add zero to single digit date in a date field in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

I have data like the below

```
1213231421312131|USER|21121|1231412|XEM|NAME|NAME|||5072020|2313||||NY|2131|||99|E|||ver.01
6454242352352352|USER|13131|7342422|XEM|NAME|NAME|||13032001|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
5131242515111233|USER|21212|2314413|XEM|NAME|NAME|||2101979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
2341313412341123|USER|62422|1124242|XEM|NAME|NAME|||23111979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
```

I need data as below

```
1213231421312131|USER|21121|1231412|XEM|NAME|NAME|||05072020|2313||||NY|2131|||99|E|||ver.01
6454242352352352|USER|13131|7342422|XEM|NAME|NAME|||13032001|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
5131242515111233|USER|21212|2314413|XEM|NAME|NAME|||02101979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
2341313412341123|USER|62422|1124242|XEM|NAME|NAME|||23111979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
```

So filed 10 is a date column, i would like to add zero to date... 7 digit to 8 digit. I have used the below command, but that command replacing Pipe symbol to space.

```
awk -F "|" '{$10 = sprintf("%08d", $10); print}' <fileName>
```

Please help me with this request

thank you
Yum

Comment: @Socowi already answered your question but you should also consider changing your date format from DDMMYYYY to YYYYMMDD so you can use it to directly sort on or select lines within a date range, e.g. with GNU awk `$10 = gensub( /(..)(..)(.*)/, "\\3\\2\\1", 1, sprintf("%08d", $10) )` or with any awk you can just use `substr()` to select/move the parts of the date, e.g. `x=sprintf("%08d", $10); $10=substr(x,5) substr(x,3,2) substr(x,1,2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` has an *input* field separator and an *output* field separator. The `print` command uses the latter. So to keep the `|` symbols, set the output field separator `OFS` too:

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{$10 = sprintf("%08d", $10); print}' yourFile
```

Or with `numfmt` from GNU coreutils (preinstalled on most Linux systems)

```
numfmt -d\| --field 10 --format %08f < yourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the input (`FS`) **and** *output* (`OFS`) separator within a BEGIN clause:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$10 = sprintf("%08d", $10); print}' <filename>
```

IMHO, it is the most convenient way to define identical input and output field separators other than space.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/aGhfq1):

```sh
s='1213231421312131|USER|21121|1231412|XEM|NAME|NAME|||5072020|2313||||NY|2131|||99|E|||ver.01
6454242352352352|USER|13131|7342422|XEM|NAME|NAME|||13032001|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
5131242515111233|USER|21212|2314413|XEM|NAME|NAME|||2101979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
2341313412341123|USER|62422|1124242|XEM|NAME|NAME|||23111979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$10 = sprintf("%08d", $10); print}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
1213231421312131|USER|21121|1231412|XEM|NAME|NAME|||05072020|2313||||NY|2131|||99|E|||ver.01
6454242352352352|USER|13131|7342422|XEM|NAME|NAME|||13032001|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
5131242515111233|USER|21212|2314413|XEM|NAME|NAME|||02101979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
2341313412341123|USER|62422|1124242|XEM|NAME|NAME|||23111979|1231||||TX|7312|||11|E|||ver.01
```

Answer (score 0):

You should accept the `awk` solution before you get answers like

```
sed -r 's/(([^|]*\|){9})([^|]{7}\|)/\10\3/' filename
```

or worse

```
paste -d "|" <(cut -d"|" -f1-9 filename) \
             <(cut -d"|" -f10 filename |sed -r 's/^.{7}$/0&/') \
             <(cut -d"|" -f11- filename)
```